Maximum Likelihood in High Dimensions
What are some examples of high-dimensional random variables for which MLE are solved using numerical methods because we are unable to explicitly solve the equations nicely? The only example to comes to mind is the multi-dimensional Cauchy random variable, however, I am not sure if it has important applications?
A while ago I was watching Stephen Boyd's lectures on convex optimization, and he mentioned that one of the many uses of numerical optimization is to solve statistical problems. However, I am unable to think of any explicit example of when do parameter estimation numerically.

Logistic regression and neural networks come to mind.

Even in low dimensions, there are examples, e.g., a t distribution with unknown degrees of freedom or the dispersion (shape) parameter of a negative binomial distribution.

Multi-class classification with a loooot of classes (e.g. words in a vocabulary) and neural nets

Dimensionality in [tag:item-response-theory] grows with the number of examinees.

how about MLE for a beta distribution? The great majority of nontrivial models do not have explicit MLEs. For example, within the class of GLMs, only Gaussian ones are analytically tractable.
